# Exporting a class ONLY as a type in a typescript definition file

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, .d.ts

Suppose that you have an ES6 library named `my-lib` like this one

```
export class Foo {
   ...
   createBar() {
      return new Bar();
   }
   ...
}
class Bar() {
   method1() {}
   method2() {}
   method3() {}
}
```

and you have to write the typescript definitions for the above library like so.

```
export class Foo() {
    ...
    public createBar():Bar;
}
export class Bar() {
   method1(): void
   method2(): void
   method3(): void
}
```

My questions is: Should the `Bar` class be exported?

If yes then by writing the following code

```
import { Bar } from 'my-lib'
```

will lead to declaring a `Bar` variable which is undefined

If no, then the following statement will be incorrect, since Bar is not imported

```
const foo = new Foo()
const bar: Bar = foo.createBar();
```

How should I define the `Bar` class so that it is exported as a type and NOT as a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve but if you don't want to expose your class directly but only its 'shape' (type) you can define it as an interface.

```
export class Foo {
    createBar(): IBar {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar {
    method1() { }
    method2() { return 'test'; }
    method3() { return true; }
}

export interface IBar {
    method1: () => void,
    method2: () => string,
    method3: () => boolean,
}

const foo = new Foo()
const bar: IBar = foo.createBar();
```

And then you import only Foo and IBar.

Comment: I actually removed the class in placed its interface instead. Thanks